# About bounties and reputation points

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I have opened a bounty, and it's not expired yet. Some questions:

1. Can I remove the bounty and get my reputation back?
2. If I delete the question, will I got my reputation points back?
3. If it expires, will the reputation points return to me?

Comment: duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: The downvotes are likely because of [lack of research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) considering questions 1 and 3 are answered right in the help center. (Mine was.) Also note, editing in commentary asking for downvote explanations is a _very bad idea_ as some people (not everyone mind) will downvote if they see that in a question. If you post that question at all, it should be a comment, not an edit to your post.

Comment: Actually I have read the StackOverflow helpcenter. Based on your comment I gone there again and saw I missed the point where the answer is. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

1. No. Once the bounty is set you've spent the points. The only way to get them back is if a moderator refunds the bounty, and that only happens in very rare circumstances.
2. Yes, but you can't delete a question with a bounty. Only a moderator can do that. See - [SO points changed (+50) for no reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason)
3. No. If you don't award the bounty or no answer qualifies (+2 and posted after you started the bounty) for the auto-award then the points are gone forever.

Comment: 2. Yes - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172556/so-points-changed-50-for-no-reason

Comment: Only a moderator can delete a bountied question, so your second point is misleading.  He couldn't delete the question even if he tried.